# How do I get Django's 'context' variables accessible to more than one view?

Tags: django, django-context

Is it possible to have the variables of a `context` block accessible to more than one view? Can one create "constants" in Django 'views.py'?

I have two pages: 'index.html' and 'post_list.html'. They both use the model 'Post', but the two pages aren't identical. So the DRY principle went out the window.

A quick search dug out some older questions about writing the variables into 'settings.py' or writing a block of code like `def settings...`

How is it done with Django 3.x?

Comment: Yes, these are *context processors*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#context-processors

Comment: I read that part of Django docs, but not sure I get it. Are you saying: Writing the variables into 'settings.py' is the way to go? I thought the 'context' block is used in views.

Comment: @YCode No you can write code which is loaded by the settings and injected into the context of every page. That way you can get those variables in any template.

Comment: @markwalker_ Guess I got it wrong. So the functions inside class-based models are all context processors. Perhaps I should re-phrase my question: How do I set up a 'context' block, like `context = { 'author' : author, 'book' : book,}` -- that gets used by several context processors (in several views)? Or is this question totally off?

Comment: @YCode if I only wanted that context in certain views, because I use class based views, I'd do that with a mixin or base view from which the others can inherit.

Comment: That's what I was getting at. Thanks! If you make it an answer, I'll accept it for others to see.